# Measurement after entanglement: eigenvalue confusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, eigenvalue

The following is written in my notes:

Let $\hat{O}$ be a hermitian operator associated with an observable $O$, with eigenvectors $\mid\phi_n\rangle$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_n$: $$ \hat{O}=\sum_n \lambda_n | \phi_n\rangle\langle\phi_n|$$ and let $|\phi\rangle=\sum_n a_n|\phi_n\rangle$ a state vector of a quantum system for which we want to measure $O$. This measurement induces the following unitary transformation when obtained with a measuring device $M$ that is in the state $|M\rangle$ before the actual measurement: $$ \left( \sum_n a_n|\phi_n\rangle\right)|M\rangle \to \sum_n a_n|\phi_n\rangle|M_n\rangle.$$ We can assume that the measuring device is accurate (i.e. $\langle M_m\mid M_n\rangle = \delta_{n,m}$). The expectation value of an arbitrary observable $\Lambda$ after the measurement of $O$ is $$ \langle \hat{\Lambda}\rangle = \sum_n\sum_m a_na_m^*\langle\phi_m\mid \hat{\Lambda}\mid\phi_n\rangle \langle M_m\mid M_n\rangle = \sum_n |a_n|^2\langle\phi_n\mid\hat{\Lambda}\mid\phi_n\rangle=\sum_n\lambda_n |a_n|^2.$$

**Question:**

I'm not sure why the very last equality holds: it implies that $\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $\hat{\Lambda}$ but I don't see why we can say this.

Comment: Is $\hat{\Lambda}$ the same as $\hat{O}$?

Comment: Not necessarily. If both are equal, then we can conclude the above easily, but otherwise not.

Comment: I think there is a disconnect in your notes: the way I see it, the first part is just a statement of the spectral theorem for a general operator $\hat{O}$, while the second part uses this for a specific operator $\hat{\Lambda}$.